# VGA Arbiter patch for the 4.4 linux kernel?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics, kvm-virtualization

So i'm trying to set up a KVM VM with GPU passthrough (GTX 660) while the host keeps using the intel iGPU (Intel Core i5 4460). Since Ubuntu 16.04 does not patch the linux kernel with the VGA Arbiter patch, I decided to patch it myself. But the only patches I can find are for older kernels, resulting in failures when I try to apply these patches to my current kernel (for which I downloaded sources using apt-get source).

Does anybody know where I can get the VGA Arbiter patch for the 4.4.0 kernel?

Answer (score 0):

Check out OVMF, it has better support than using the VGA Arbiter patch.

OVMF brings UEFI support to virtual machines.

I currently do not have more detailed information' however, the OVMF keyword will enhance your searches.

Comment: yeah well, the problem is that my Graphics Card does not have a UEFI bios so OVMF was a no-go for me. I finally just went ahead and compiled a 4.2.0 kernel for ubuntu with the VGA arbitration patch myself ;).